# How to remove any JavaScript code From a Dom element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Question:** How to remove any JavaScript code (functions, variables, events etc.) which is Inside a Dom element (div)

**Note:** This is not similar question like removing content from Dom element.

**My Scenario:**

My site has a menu. When I click on a menu item I am loading corresponding html file which also contains JavaScript code inside a div element(id=content).
When click on menu I am doing following code

```
function changeMenu(params){
  //need something here to remove previous js codes before load the file
  $('#content').load(params['file'],function (){
        ///ohters code
    })
}
```

It is working fine for first click and executing the JavaScript code as well inside that file.
**But problem is it also increase executing JavaScript code number of times I click on the menu.  Also when I load another file still previous JavaScript code executing because I had interval function there.** Aslo if there is variable declared like this `let x=10`
it showing follwing error when I click the menu again

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared

**Asking Solution:**
Is it posible remove all JavaScript codes when I click on the menu and How?

I do not want to do manullay add/remove events,timers for every pages Becuase events and events types are different for differnt pages. Bellow Sample code to understand the problem.

**Sample Code**

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <button onclick="changeMenu('a.html')">Load A</button>
            <button onclick="changeMenu('b.html')">Load B</button>
        </header>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
        <script>
            function changeMenu(file){
                $('#content').load(file,function (){
                    ///others code
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**a.html**

```
This is A
<script>
    //let x=10;
    //number of events and events type are unknows for different files 
    $(document).on('click','button',function (event){
            console.log("menuClick from A")
    })
    setInterval(() => {
        //code for A
        console.log("I am interval A 1st line")
        console.log("I am interval A 2nd line")
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

**b.html**

```
This is B
<script>
    //let x=10;
    setInterval(() => {
        //code for B
        console.log("I am interval B 1st line")
        console.log("I am interval B 2nd line")
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Please Run the index.html,click the buttons and watch the console log.

Comment: @imhvost added sample code. Hope you can understand now.

Comment: But another matter, now it is clear!  Added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How would I do it? I would create a `сlass` in the files being loaded with methods that initialize the necessary functions and data on insertion (`setInterval`, `setTimeout`, events, etc), and destroy them when another file is loaded.
This `class` would be set as a property of `window` to have global access to it. Something like this:

**Loaded file:**

```html
This is A a
<script>

;(function (){
  class ContentCode {
    constructor() {
      this.intervals = [];
      this.events = [];
    }
    init() {
      this.intervals.push( setInterval( () => console.log('A1'), 1000 ) );
      this.intervals.push( setInterval( () => console.log('A2'), 1000 ) );
        
      this.events.push( $('#content').on( 'click', () => console.log('click A') ) );
    }
    destroy() {
      this.intervals.map( el => clearInterval(el) );
      this.events.map( el => Object.keys( $._data( $(el)[0], 'events' ) ).map( eventType => el.off(eventType) ) );
    }
  }

  window.contentCode = new ContentCode;
})();
  
</script>
```

**index.html**

```html
<button onclick="changeMenu('a.html')">Load A</button>
<button onclick="changeMenu('b.html')">Load B</button>
<div id="content"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function changeMenu(file) {
    $('#content').empty();
    if (window.contentCode) {
      window.contentCode.destroy();
      delete window.contentCode;
    }
    $('#content').load(file,function() {
      if (window.contentCode) {
         window.contentCode.init();
      }
    })
 }
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://imhvost.github.io/76105368.html)

---

*Also, I'll keep my previous answer where I thought you just needed to remove all javascript from the downloaded files.*

---

Method `.load()` immediately places loaded data in element. That is, you can't do anything with the html before pasting.
You can use [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method and remove all `<script>` tags before pasting. Something like this:

```html
<button onclick="changeMenu('a.html')">Load A</button>
<button onclick="changeMenu('b.html')">Load B</button>

<div id="content"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeMenu(file) {
  $.get(file, function(html) {
    html = $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
    html.find('script').remove();
    $('#content').append(html);
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: `jQuery.load('http://example.com/page body')` syntax (url followed by selector) will also not execute JavaScript in the content.

Comment: @Salman A - Yes, this is if it is known in advance that the `body` does not contain `script` tags

Comment: @imhvost You are removing script tag. But I want that javascript What I am doing when I click on menu I load that page. It means I removing previous codes inside the #content and loading new codes. But problem is previous codes is still running. If you remove that script then How can I use them?

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question after all. Now, as if, I understand what is needed. Do you know the javascript code that will be in the files, do you create it yourself?

Comment: @imhvost thanks for you efford. You are doing for intervals. what about other events. As example if I have click event inside a.html like this  `$(document).on('click','button',function (event){
                console.log("menuClick from a.html")})` what will happen if I click 2nd button.

Comment: In your comment, the event is applied to `$(document)` and checks the `button` via `event.target`. That is, the event listener is in no way related to the downloaded files.  
If you set event listeners in the file you download, set them in the `init()` method and remove them accordingly in the `destroy()` method. By analogy with the `setInterval()` in my example.  `EventTarget.addEventListener()` (`.on()` in jQuery) in `init()` class method, and `EventTarget.removeEventListener()` (`.off()` in jQuery) in `destroy()` class method.

Comment: Added a `#content` click event listener to my example and its deletion when other content is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to remove and abort imported javascript code based on your code logic. In your case (`setInterval` code), you can abort it using `clearInterval`. In other case (*let say XMLHttpRequest*), you can abort it using `.abort()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort). Each case has different solutions.

---

**Edit: Using `iframe`**

The only solution I think is importing the external code using `iframe`. With this, external javascript code will run in a separate environment so it can be aborted when `src` attribute has changed. You can use `frameBorder="0"` to remove the iframe's border.

Code: https://playcode.io/abortcode

Demo: https://abortcode.playcode.io/index.html

---

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <button onclick="changeMenu('a.html')">Load A</button>
    <button onclick="changeMenu('b.html')">Load B</button>
  </header>
  <iframe id="content" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
  <script>
    function changeMenu(file){
      $('#content').attr('src',file);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. I am using electronjs [ipcRenderer.on](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener) and I cannot remove all listeners. only those whose are inside that div.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam can you give some code examples?

Comment: Your code is currenlty removing intervals where you defined the varaible globally. But in real case every file contains lots of code like intervals,,listeners(click,mouse...,keyboard, etc) and all are unknown because different programs works on differnet file.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Oh, I see. How about using `iframe` instead of `div`? I have updated the answer.